# How to improve the texture of popping/bursting boba spheres with reverse spherification?

Tags: texture, molecular-gastronomy, spherification

I'm trying to make boba spheres using reverse spherification, but it doesn't have the texture like the ones you get from asian supermarkets, the one with a "hard, plastic texture" that burst in your mouth.

The ones I make only result in a soft outer membrane that easily pops, unlike the one mentioned above.

I've tried the following already:

1. Higher alginate bath (1500g of water with 17g alginate, mixed with blender)
2. High calcium lactate solution (1500g of flavorful liquid with 15g calcium lactate)
3. Adding guar gum with the calcium lactate solution
4. Using distilled water, not tap water for both calcium lactate/sodium alginate mixture

If I did it however with direct spherification, it does yield tougher membrane but it would only lasts like a good 15min till the whole batch turns jelly, which sucks if you're preparing it for parties or catering.

What am I missing here? Any additional chemical? Some procedure perhaps?